# How to resolve LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi_c

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, installation

I would like to know how to resolve next error seen when executed `require` command on the console after installed `Ruby 2.2.1` Windows installer and `Ruby gem 2.4.6`.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi_c
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require'
```

Is this something like DLL?

Comment: whats the `ffi` gem version ?

Comment: Hi Shivam, ffi library version is 1.9.8 x64-mingw32.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65000467/12544391, e.g. adding `gem "ffi"` to `Gemfile` fixed it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you read the [requirement](https://github.com/ffi/ffi#requirements) documentation for `ffi`, you can see:

> You need a sane building environment in order to compile the
>   extension. At a minimum, you will need:
>
> - A C compiler (e.g. Xcode on OSX, gcc on everything else)
> - libffi development library - this is commonly in the libffi-dev or
>     libffi-devel

This means the gem is not pre-compiled, and has to compile code when it installs. Which in turn means if you are running on a PC you will need to install the Ruby development kit for windows, aka '[devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/)', you can get it from the [downloads page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) on the rubyinstaller site

Download and install devkit first, then open a new command line window followed by:

```
gem install ffi
```

Refer to this SO for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988119/3035830

Comment: Thanks, Shivam. However, during installation of v1.0.9 ffi after successfully having installed ffi, I encountered next error, which says; Fetching: ffi-1.0.9.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        The 'ffi' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Comment: So couldn't install ffi version 1.0.9 successfully yet unfortunately.

Comment: After avoiding the use of the latest version of ruby as of Ruby 2.2.1 (x64) but rather 2.0.0-p643 (x64), installation of Ruby, its gem and devkit were all succeeded.

Comment: Looks like a recent upgrade in Xcode caused this.  Uninstalling and installing again fixed the problem.  Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

Entire error I got as below, but on *Mac*:

```
/Users/mayuresh.srivastava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.7/ffi_c (LoadError)

/Users/mayuresh.srivastava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `require': dlopen(/Users/mayuresh.srivastava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/mayuresh.srivastava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/mayuresh.srivastava/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle
```

I checked ffi, it was already there:

```
mayuresh.srivastava$ gem list ffi

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ffi (1.15.4)
public_suffix (4.0.6)
```

Still I installed ffi again, and it worked.

```
mayuresh.srivastava$ gem install ffi
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.15.4
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.15.4
Installing ri documentation for ffi-1.15.4
Done installing documentation for ffi after 11 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a minor mistake in ffi's regex in C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\ffi-1.9.8-x64-mingw32\lib\ffi.rb which makes it incorrectly think you are running ruby 2.1.x

it tests for RUBY_VERSION =~ /2.1/ which catches '2.2.1' whereas it should test for RUBY_VERSION =~ /^2.1/ with a start of line character in.

it should be:

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.8/
      require '1.8/ffi_c'
    elsif RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1\.9/
      require '1.9/ffi_c'
    elsif RUBY_VERSION =~ /^2\.0/
      require '2.0/ffi_c'
    elsif RUBY_VERSION =~ /^2\.1/
      require '2.1/ffi_c'
    elsif RUBY_VERSION =~ /^2\.2/
      require '2.2/ffi_c'
    else
      require 'ffi_c'
    end
```

I see that it has now been fixed https://github.com/ffi/ffi/commit/4168ef3dbd56a7b52978efb2ff7d0dc448f8f8f1

Answer (score 2):

In my case literally none of these helped, after a 6 hours debug and search ..

What actually worked for me :

```
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

Comment: Thanks! it really helped. nice and simple

Comment: this worked for me, but only sort of: I still get a segmentation fault using Guard (but not '$rails test'). Go figure. Still, I can move forward, for now, and I found this answer after only 3 hours of struggling... so thanks! ;)