# Flutter - reinstalling App causes build to crash

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an app idea and ran into an issue with `shared_preferences`. After trying out a couple of things I stumbled on a post on stackoverflow to delete the app and reinstalling it again. After uninstalling the app I tried to run

`$ flutter run`

again but it doesn't build.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 mini in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             937ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
```

I tried to clean the installation:

```
rm ios/Podfile
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub run
cd ios
pod init
pod update
flutter clean && flutter run
```

on `flutter pub run` the script runs to another error: `pub finished with exit code 64`

On the app I have custom fonts, and images from the assets folder enabled. The only dependency I'm using is `shared_preferences: ^2.0.12`

I pasted the full log here: https://pastebin.com/5XyDT0PT

edit:

I tried to reinstall cocoapods but still get the same error message:

```
$ brew upgrade ruby
$ gem uninstall cocoapods
$ gem install cocoapods
```

anyone having simular issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this error too. Learn to look at the error log outputs. I believe you need this command

> gem install ffi

see here for more details:
[How to resolve LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi_c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092233/how-to-resolve-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-ffi-c)